# prepare statement in php not work

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Hi i get a value with post methos and i want to check it with function func_check_seven_userid()

when i use :

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM content  where content_id= ".$this->seven);
 $stmt->execute();
```

it work.

but when i use :

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM content WHERE content_id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $this->seven));
```

it is not work!!!

my complet code is :

```
<?php

class insert_content {
private $conn;
private $seven;
private $row_id;
//**********************************************************************
function connect() {
    include 'db_connection.php';
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
 //************************************************************************
   private function func_check_seven_userid() {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM content WHERE content_id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $this->seven));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $this->row_id = $row[0];
    if ($this->row_id) {
        echo 'yes';
    }
     else {
        echo 'no';
  }
}
 //****************************************************************
function __construct($parms) {
    $this->connect();
    $this->seven = $parms['seven'];
    $this->func_check_seven_userid();
}
function __destruct() {
    $this->conn = null;
 }
 }
if (isset($_POST['seven'])) {
$parms = array('seven' => ($_POST['seven']));
$class = new insert_content($parms);
}
?>
```

thanks for help

Comment: Try using binding with question marks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

on http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Here the statement is prepared with `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY`

Maybe it does the difference. Hope it helps